# fade bottom-border-color when class is added and removed from input.

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to animate using css rules the border-bottom-color but its not animating for me when the class is added to my element or removed from my element. So when a input field is invalid the class is added and I want the animation to fade in. I'm using React as my javascript. But I don't want to use js to animate something as simple as this.

Anyone know why this might be happening.

```
.group{
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  transition: border-bottom-color 2s;
}
.invalid,
.error {
  input,
  .group{
    color: red;
    border-bottom-color: red;
  }
}
.valid {
  input:focus {
    border-bottom-color: green;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's valid in css to use nesting construction like `.error { .group { color: red }}` ? https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Comment: Are you trying do alter the css in react or in the regular DOM?

Comment: @iofjuupasli  yes Its scss and the nesting is correct, but thanks for checking. pax i'm trying to alter it in css. I just mentioned React as what I was using as a library to create and update my elements classes if an input is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need transition and border-bottom properties on your `input` too.

```css
.group,
input {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  transition: border-bottom-color 2s;
}

.invalid input,
.invalid .group,
.error input,
.error .group {
  color: red;
  border-bottom-color: red;
}

.valid input:focus {
  border-bottom-color: #20ae80;
}
```

```html
<div class="valid">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ksav. I'm adding and removing the className invalid from my React element. Its showing the red border but its not animating ?

Comment: I did add the markup. All React is doing is adding or removing the invalid class on the input. As I said this works as the red is showing and hiding. The thing that is not working is the animation of it.

Comment: There's no markup in your question. What's not working in the answer above?